# Unexpected output in browser with CGI::Fast to_json

Tags: json, perl, fastcgi

I have a server with openSUSE Leap 15.3.

On this server I run Apache 2.4.43 with apache2-mod_fcgi.

I have the following program: `test.fcgi`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON;
use CGI::Fast;

while (CGI::Fast->new) {
   print "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

   $array{strng} = "öäüöä";

   $strng_json1 = to_json (\%array);
   $strng_json2 = "{\"strng\":\"öäüöä\"}";

   if ($strng_json1 eq $strng_json2) {
      print "\$strng_json1 and \$strng_json2 are equal <br><br>";
   }

   print "\$strng_json1: $strng_json1 <br>";
   print "\$strng_json2: $strng_json2 <br>";
}
```

If I start this program in a browser I see the output:

```
$strng_json1 and $strng_json2 are equal

$strng_json1: {"strng":"Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼Ã¶Ã¤"}
$strng_json2: {"strng":"öäüöä"}
```

What I don't understand is why, if `$strng_json1` and `$strng_json2` are equal, in the browser I see two different strings.

Comment: Step one: always `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in perl scripts.

Comment: Step two: read https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8 and https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro and https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON#ENCODING/CODESET-FLAG-NOTES

Comment: Re "*`$strng_json1 eq $strng_json2`*", Good test. Proves a bug in CGI::Fast. Or rather in FCGI, which is used by CGI::Fast. What version of FCGI are you using? (`perl -MFCGI=9999 -e1` will tell you.)

Comment: From looking at the source code, it looks like the bug in FCGI has been fixed since that version.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with a bug in FCGI (used by CGI::Fast), and bugs of your own. Fix yours by adding `use utf8;` and encoding your output.  (Normally, I'd suggest using `use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";` to handle the latter, but that won't work here.) The bug in FCGI is unlikely to bother you then.

---

Test your solution with

- A data structure that contains a string that contains characters > 0xFF.
- A data structure that contains a string that contains characters > 0x7F, but none that contains character > 0xFF.